# Cakephp: BelongsTo Relationship

Tags: cakephp

I want to model the following simple relationship:

One Passenger belongs to a Car; One Car has many Passengers.

The passenger table has an id and Car_id column, the Car table has one id column.

My models look like this:

```
<?php
class Passenger extends AppModel {
   var $name = 'Passenger';
   var $belongsTo = 'Car';
} ?>
```

and

```
<?php
class Car extends AppModel {
   var $name = 'Car';
   var $hasMany = array (
      'Passenger' => array (
            'className' => 'Passenger',
            'foreignKey' => 'car_id'
         )
   );
}
?>
```

and my add Passenger .ctp looks like this:

```
<?php
echo $this->Form->create('Passenger');
    echo $this->Form->input('car_id');
    echo $this->Form->end('Save');
?>
```

BUt when I access the page to add a passenger, all I see is an empty drop down box. Is there an additional step I must take in order to populate the dropbox with all cars?

Comment: +1 for cake php good question for new to cake php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, you have forgotten to mention the `belongsTo` relation in your Passenger model:

```
<?php
class Passenger extends AppModel {
   var $name = 'Passenger';
   var $belongsTo = array('Car');
}
?>
```

Next, in the corresponding action of your **controller**, you will need to obtain a `list` of all the cars from the database, and set it to the plural form of the model's variable ($cars). You would do that like so:

```
$cars = $this->Passenger->Car->find('list');
$this->set(compact('cars'));
```

This will convert the `car_id` input field into a drop down list with the populated information.

HTH.

Comment: hey in this case I need to include 'Car' model in controller?

Answer (score 2):

The Passenger will only know about the car with which it is associated - at this point, none.

In the add method in the passenger controller, do

`$this->Car->find('list');`

and pass the result into your view:

```
$this->set('cars',$cars);
```

In the view, give the $cars variable as the value for $options in the field declaration:

```
echo $this->Form->input('car_id', array('options' => $cars));
```

Alternatively, you can do something like:

```
echo $this->Form->input('Car.id', array('options' => $cars));
```

Comment: Hey, you can't access `Car` directly in the `PassengersController`. You would have to access it through Passenger. Also, the options field for `car_id` is automagically taken to be `$cars` (if available). :)

Comment: 2. I prefer verbosity as it makes later maintenance easier.

Comment: Assigning the array to the input is useful if not using standard naming conventions.

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->CompanyCashback->bindModel(array('belongsTo' => array(
        'CompanyBranch' => array('className' => 'CompanyBranch', 'foreignKey' => false, 'conditions' => array('CompanyCashback.publisher_id = CompanyBranch.publisher_id && CompanyBranch.branch_type = "online" ')),
        'PersonalInformation' => array('className' => 'PersonalInformation', 'foreignKey' => false, 'conditions' => array('CompanyCashback.publisher_id = PersonalInformation.user_id')),
        'Country' => array('className' => 'Country', 'foreignKey' => false, 'conditions' => array('PersonalInformation.country_id = Country.id')),
        'User' => array('className' => 'User', 'foreignKey' => false, 'conditions' => array('PersonalInformation.user_id = User.id')))
));
```